# How can you define how objects are compared in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison, equals

I want to define a JavaScript class, Foo.

```
Foo = function(value){
    this.value = value;
};
```

I will create "instances" of my Foo:

```
foo1 = new Foo(1);
foo2 = new Foo(1);
```

and I want my instances of Foo to be comparable with each other using the standard == equality operator:

```
foo1 == foo2;      // this should be true
```

I can not find a way to do this. I thought I was on to something with the `valueOf()` function, but this is only useful when one side of the comparison is a primitive, not as above where both are of type object.

Have I missed something really simple akin to Ruby's

```
def ==(obj); end
```

Comment: have you tried "foo1 === foo2" ?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10539938/632951

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript does not have operator overloading. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript) covering your question.

Answer (score 5):

Not in a clean way...

```
Foo = function (value){
    this.value = value;
};
```

Override the toString function of your own object:

```
Foo.prototype.toString = function( ){ return this.value.toString(); }
```

Creating two test objects:

```
foo1 = new Foo(1);
foo2 = new Foo(1);
```

If the values of your objects is strings or numbers, you can have the javascript engine to convert your objects to a string by adding them to an empty string:

```
alert( ""+foo1 === ""+foo2 ); //Works for strings and numbers
```

The same thing but cleaner:

```
alert( foo1.toString() === foo2.toString() ); //Works for strings and numbers
```

If the values of your objects is numeric only, you can use the unary + operator to convert the object to a number:

```
alert( +foo1 === +foo2 ); //Works for numbers
```

However, I recommend you to both define the toString as above and also an equals:

```
Foo.prototype.equals=function(b){return this.toString() === b.toString();}
```

And then call it like this:

```
alert ( foo1.equals(foo2) );
```

Since you now have defined toString you can:

```
alert(foo1); // Alerts the value of foo1 instead of "[Object object]"
alert("foo1: " + foo1); // Alerts "foo1: 1". Useful when debugging.
```

Comment: You can ofcourse put whatever you want in the equals method to determinate if the two objects are equal enough without being the same object.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is in this regard like its namesake Java: No operator overloading. Use a custom method like `equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using javascript. You have to write your own function e.g. `isEqual()`