# Boolean operations on sets of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Using ES6 sets, I can do this:

```
let ints = new Set([1,2,3])
console.log(ints.has(3))
```

And it prints `true` because `3` *is* in the set.

But what about arrays? E.g.

```
let coordinates = new Set([[1,1], [1,2], [2,0]])
console.log(coordinates.has([1,2]))
```

this prints `false`.

[As you can see in this CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/peterbe/pen/dYwMmM?editors=001)

So, without first turning the coordinates into strings (e.g `['1,1', '1,2', '2,0']`) how can I work with arrays in sets as if the array was something hashable?

Comment: Two different objects are never `===` to each other.

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't allow one to customize the equality criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Set and Map instances are based on the `===` comparison (except for `NaN`), two different arrays will never compare the same and so your example correctly results in `false`. However:

```
var a = [1, 1], b = [1, 2], c = [1, 3];
var s = new Set([a, b, c]);
console.log(s.has(a));
```

will print `true`.