# JavaScript Set() with specific key to hash on

Tags: javascript, typescript, set

I have a few objects that are all disparate, but which all have an `id` field. I want to create a Set() to hold these, but am not sure how to specify this field to the Set constructor/prototype/etc. Is this doable?

Let's say I have two types of objects (I'll give typescript definitions for simplicity's sake):

```
interface Thing1 {
  id: string;
  someData: string[]
}

interface Thing2 {
  id: string;
  someString: string;
  someOtherString: string
}
```

Now, I have two Arrays of these things, let's call them

```
array1: Thing1[];
array2: Thing2[];
```

What I'd like to do is create a `new Set(array1)` and then `add` each `Thing2` in `array2`, performing a conditional merge of the two arrays.

The unique key in each of these is the `id` field - I was hoping there was some overloaded constructor or similar pattern that could be given a lambda (a la `new Set(array1, (item) => item.id)`, maybe) which would specify the key to hash on for identity.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Explain yourself better, and add code to show what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Is this what you are asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set

Comment: @Andrew yeah that's roughly it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a Set is pretty straightforward...

Imagine that you have two objects like so:

```
const obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  prop: 'Foo'
};

const obj2 = {
  id: 2,
  prop: 'Bar'
};
```

To create your Set with references to these objects, you can do this:

```
let set = new Set([obj1, obj2]);
```

Or that:

```
let set = new Set();
set.add(obj1).add(obj2);
```

Since a Set is an iterable object, you can use a `for...of` loop to retrieve all your data:

```
for (const obj of set) {
  console.log(`${obj.id}:${obj.prop}`);
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I meant - I've added some examples, but it looks like the answer is just "You can't do that in JS"

Comment: Oh, I see... I am sorry, your description was a bit unclear. I thought you wanted to know how to use the data structure in a traditional way. ;)