# How to pass test cases in 4sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here my code to solve the [4sum question](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/) in leetcode

```
var fourSum = function(ns, tar) {
    ns.sort((a, b) => a-b);

    let res=[], out=false;
    for(let i=0; i<ns.length-3; i++) {
        if(ns[i] !== ns[i-1]) {
            out = threeSum(ns, i+1, tar-ns[i]);

            for(let item of out) {
                res.push([ns[i], ...item]);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
};

var threeSum = function(ns, ind, tar) {
    let res=[], out=false;
    for(let i=ind; i<ns.length-2; i++) {
        if(ns[i] !== ns[i-1]) {
            out = twoSum(ns, i+1, tar-ns[i]);

            for(let item of out) {
                res.push([ns[i], ...item]);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

var twoSum = function(ns, ind, tar) {    
    let set = new Set();
    let res = [];
    for(let i=ind; i<ns.length; i++) {
        if(set.has(tar-ns[i])) {
            res.push([tar-ns[i], ns[i]]);
            while(ns[i] === ns[i+1]) i++;
        } else {
            set.add(ns[i]);
        }    
    }

    return res;
}
```

Currently it is not able to pass

```
case 1:
[0, 0, 0, 0]
0
```

if I remove `if(ns[i] !== ns[i-1]) {` It is able to pass case 1, but fail at

```
case 2:
[-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3]
0
```

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  Try tracing the logic as you traverse your multi-level solution.  I believe you'll get help more readily if you document your approach, use meaningful variable names, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the test case: `[0, 0, 0, 0], sum==0` again.

If i ===0, when landing on this `if(ns[i] !== ns[i-1]) {`

it becomes `if(ns[0] !== ns[0-1]) {`

`out = threeSum(ns, i+1, tar-ns[i]);` is able to execute.

Basically, it means the `1st num` in each `?Sum` needs to be ignored

**So I made the following changes in 3sum func**

`if(i-1 >= ind && ns[i] === ns[i-1]) continue;`

Full code:

```
var fourSum = function(ns, tar) {
    ns.sort((a, b) => a-b);

    let res=[], out=false;
    for(let i=0; i<ns.length-3; i++) {
        // can get in
        if(ns[i] !== ns[i-1]) {            
            out = threeSum(ns, i+1, tar-ns[i]);

            // each set add ns[i], 4 # now
            for(let item of out) {
                res.push([ns[i], ...item]);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
};

var threeSum = function(ns, ind, tar) {
    let res=[], out=false;
    for(let i=ind; i<ns.length-2; i++) {
        if(i-1 >= ind && ns[i] === ns[i-1]) continue;

        out = twoSum(ns, i+1, tar-ns[i]);

        for(let item of out) {
            res.push([ns[i], ...item]);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

var twoSum = function(ns, ind, tar) {    
    let set = new Set();
    let res = [];
    for(let i=ind; i<ns.length; i++) {
        if(set.has(tar-ns[i])) {
            res.push([tar-ns[i], ns[i]]);
            while(ns[i] === ns[i+1]) i++;
        } else {
            set.add(ns[i]);
        }    
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use 4 `for` loops to solve this ? Basically you take 4 loops for each `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`. Then if they sum up to the `target` value you just add them to the result array called `res` (in increasing order).

At the end you just have to make sure that `res` has only unique values. For that you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772423/1764528) which converts the arrays to string and then checks for duplicates and removes the duplicates.

Here is my accepted solution :

```
var fourSum = function(nums, target) {

    var res = [];
    for(var a=0; a < nums.length; a++){
        for(var b=a+1; b < nums.length; b++){
            for(var c=b+1; c < nums.length; c++){
                for(var d=c+1; d < nums.length; d++){
                    if(nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] + nums[d] == target){
                        res.push( [nums[a], nums[b], nums[c], nums[d]].sort() )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var res_set  = new Set(res.map(JSON.stringify));
    var res_uniq = Array.from(res_set).map(JSON.parse);

    return res_uniq;
};
```

Comment: @analogman Feel free to add your effective solution as an answer.

Comment: I personally think it is an easy understanding solution. Good job