# How to create a Map of a string and an array of pair of strings/Integers. The array should contain all unique pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects in my NodeJS project. Each object contains two values -

```
[{
    travelDate: "2023-04-02",
    busNumber: "MKLK890"
}]
```

By using the busNumber and travelDate I am extracting the city id and operator id for each object. For every travelDate I need an array that contains all unique pairs of city is and operator id.
For example, I have the following array of objects with their corresponding cityId and operatorId -

```
[{
    travelDate: "2023-04-02",
    busNumber: "MKLK890"        // cityId: 17, operatorId: 15
},
{
    travelDate: "2023-04-02",
    busNumber: "MKLK891"        // cityId: 17, operatorId: 15
},
{
    travelDate: "2023-04-03",
    busNumber: "MKLK890"        // cityId: 16, operatorId: 23
},
{
    travelDate: "2023-04-03",
    busNumber: "MKLK891"        // cityId: 16, operatorId: 25
}]
```

The Map I want for the above data should look like this -

```
2023-04-02: [{17, 15}],
2023-04-03: [{16,23}, {16, 25}]
```

The code I have written does not return unique pairs -

```
let busRecordsCityOprHash = {};
for(let currentRow of data) {
    const travelDate = currentRow['Travel Date'];
    const busNumber = currentRow['Bus Number'];
    const distance = currentRow['Settlement Distance'];

    let operatorId, cityId;
    let busDetails = await busDayWiseService.getOperatorAndCityIdOfBus({ filter: {busNumber: busNumber.toUpperCase(), fromDate: getZeroTimeDate(travelDate)}})
    if(busDetails){
      operatorId = busDetails.operatorId;
      cityId = busDetails.cityId; 
    } 

    const cityOprPair = [cityId, operatorId];
    if(!busRecordsCityOprHash[travelDate]) {
      busRecordsCityOprHash[travelDate] = new Set();
    }
    busRecordsCityOprHash[travelDate].add(cityOprPair)
  }
```

Please modify my code to get the required output. Also tell how to iterate the modified data structure?

Comment: I would like you to write a **code snippet** with a dummy object having a `cityId` and `operatorId`. Your example object still needs to be shown with the mentioned two data. Once that is done, we will be able to provide a much better solution.

Comment: A set follows the same rule as the rest of javascript for objects: 2 objects built separately with the same properties/values will no test as equal because they have a different reference, only objects assigned by reference with `=` will test as equal. This is the same for `indexOf` which finds an object in an array only if it is the same exact reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772320/map-set-to-maintain-unique-array-of-arrays-javascript maybe this will help