# X,Y,Z coordinates of an object in forge viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to draw svg/pointcloud points on individual elements in Autodesk Forge. How to get **(x,y,z)** coordinates of elements.

Is there a way to extract positions of individual object so that we have the position vector in world space.

What I tried so far:

- I cant seem to understand how to use the positions array as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513656/how-to-get-coordinates-i-e-vertices-from-an-object) using
      `frags = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy( viewer.model, fragId )`

  `positions = frags.geometry.vb`
- [Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MeshData.js](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MeshData/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MeshData.js) gives me the vertices of triangles (meshes/fragments) the element is made of.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a self-contained extension that you can add to your viewer and illustrates how to get the component position:
[image]

Check [this](https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions) repo and the [TransformationExplorerExtension](https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions/blob/master/assets/js/extensions/transformationExplorer.js)

The code responsible for extracting the transformation matrix is:

```js
getFragmentWorldMatrixByNodeId(nodeId) {
        let result = {
            fragId: [],
            matrix: [],
        };
        let viewer = this.viewer;
        this.tree.enumNodeFragments(nodeId, function (frag) {

            let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, frag);
            let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

            fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(matrix);

            result.fragId.push(frag);
            result.matrix.push(matrix);
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Great repo. Thank you :)

Comment: @anahom Why not accept the answer?