# Using map() on an iterator

Tags: javascript, dictionary, syntax, ecmascript-6, iterator

Say we have a Map: `let m = new Map();`, using `m.values()` returns a map iterator.

But I can't use `forEach()` or `map()` on that iterator and implementing a while loop on that iterator seems like an anti-pattern since ES6 offer functions like `map()`.

So is there a way to use `map()` on an iterator?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can use third party libraries like `lodash` `map` function which supports Map as well.

Comment: Map itself has a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) for iterating over its key-value pairs.

Comment: Converting the iterator to an array and map on it like `Array.from(m.values()).map(...)` works, but I think it's not the best way to do this.

Comment: which problem like you to solve with using an iterator while an array would fit better for using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm using a general set like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783624/4279201

Comment: [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) lets you do `map` and many other operations on any iterator.

Comment: `[...m].map(([key, value]) => value /* or any func*/)`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The **simplest** and **least performant** way to do this is:

```js
Array.from(m).map(([key,value]) => /* whatever */)
```

Better yet

```js
Array.from(m, ([key, value]) => /* whatever */))
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes any iterable or array-like thing and converts it into an array! As Daniel points out in the comments, we can add a mapping function to the conversion to remove an iteration and subsequently an intermediate array.

Using `Array.from` will move your performance from *`O(1)`* to *`O(n)`* as @hraban points out in the comments. Since `m` is a `Map`, and they can't be infinite, we don't have to worry about an infinite sequence. For most instances, this will suffice.

There are a couple of other ways to loop through a map.

### Using `forEach`

```js
m.forEach((value,key) => /* stuff */ )
```

### Using `for..of`

```js
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero');
myMap.set(1, 'one');
for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
// 0 = zero
// 1 = one
```

Comment: Can maps have an infinite length?

Comment: @ktilcu for an iterator: yes. a .map on an iterator can be thought of as a transform on the generator, which returns an iterator itself. popping one element calls the underlying iterator, transforms the element, and returns that.

Comment: I think the `Array.from` portion guarantees the finite set. I do understand how a generator could provide a lazy and infinite sequence but thats not part of this question.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it turns what could be an O(1) memory algorithm into an O(n) one, which is quite serious for larger datasets. Aside from, of course, requiring finite, non-streamable iterators. The title of the question is "Using map() on an iterator", I disagree that lazy and infinite sequences are not part of the question. That's precisely how people use iterators. The "map" was only an example ("Say.."). The good thing about this answer is its simplicity, which is very important.

Comment: @hraban Thanks for adding to this discussion. I can update the answer to include a few caveats just so future travelers have the info front and center. When it comes down to it we will often have to make the decision between simple and optimal performance. I will usually side with simpler (to debug, maintain, explain) over performance.

Comment: Generator/iterator support in JS is very lacking. In Python it's easy to deal with these things. I use Py to process massive data sets streamed to/from Postgres databases, and it's just as easy as using simple arrays. Different use cases, though. Usually in JS you aren't doing any long-running synchronous tasks like that. But it would be nice to be able to use those annoying iterator interfaces without converting to arrays.

Comment: @ktilcu You can instead call `Array.from(m, ([key,value]) => /* whatever */)` (notice the mapping function is inside the `from`) and then no intermediate array is created ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Description)). It still moves from O(1) to O(n), but at least iteration and mapping happen in just one full iteration.

Comment: Is it `[key, value]` or `[value, key]` like here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from

Answer (score 35):

Other answers here are... Weird. They seem to be re-implementing parts of the iteration protocol. You can just do this:

```js
function* mapIter(iterable, callback) {
  for (let x of iterable) {
    yield callback(x);
  }
}
```

and if you want a concrete result just use the spread operator `...`.

```js
[...mapIter([1, 2, 3], x => x**2)]
```

Comment: nice! is there an iterable prototype to which i could this as a "." function so that i can use it as `[1, 2, 3].mapIter(x => x**2)`?  (not just for arrays but any iterable)

Answer (score 30):

This simplest and most performant way is to use the second argument to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to achieve this:

```js
const map = new Map()
map.set('a', 1)
map.set('b', 2)

Array.from(map, ([key, value]) => `${key}:${value}`)
// ['a:1', 'b:2']
```

This approach works for any **non-infinite** iterable. And it avoids having to use a separate call to `Array.from(map).map(...)` which would iterate through the iterable twice and be worse for performance.

Answer (score 29):

You could define another iterator function to loop over this:

```js
function* generator() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        yield i;
    }
}

function* mapIterator(iterator, mapping) {
    for (let i of iterator) {
        yield mapping(i);
    }
}

let values = generator();
let mapped = mapIterator(values, (i) => {
    let result = i*2;
    console.log(`x2 = ${result}`);
    return result;
});

console.log('The values will be generated right now.');
console.log(Array.from(mapped).join(','));
```

Now you might ask: why not just use `Array.from` instead? Because this will run through the entire iterator, save it to a (temporary) array, iterate it again and *then* do the mapping. If the list is huge (or even potentially infinite) this will lead to unnecessary memory usage.

Of course, if the list of items is fairly small, using `Array.from` should be more than sufficient.

Comment: How can a finite amount of memory hold an infinite data structure?

Comment: it doesn't, that's the point. Using this you can create "data streams" by chaining an iterator source to a bunch of iterator transforms and finally a consumer sink. E.g. for streaming audio processing, working with huge files, aggregators on databases, etc.

Comment: I like this answer.  Can anyone recommend a library that offers Array-like methods on iterables?

Comment: `mapIterator()` does not guarantee that underlying iterator will be properly closed (`iterator.return()` called) unless the return value's next was called at least once. See: https://repeater.js.org/docs/safety

Comment: Why are you manually using the iterator protocol instead of just a `for .. of .. loop`?

Comment: @cowlicks I have no idea! Maybe there were compatibility issues or I was confused believing it was a TypeScript-only construct. I've updated it now to use a for .. of .. loop instead as this is much clearer.

Comment: Is there some way to write this with fp-ts? Haven’t used it myself, but this seems  like the thing it is meant for!?!

Answer (score 10):

There is a proposal, that brings multiple helper functions to `Iterator`: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers ([rendered](https://tc39.es/proposal-iterator-helpers/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object))

You can use it today by utilizing [`core-js-pure`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js-pure):

```js
import { from as iterFrom } from "core-js-pure/features/iterator";

// or if it's working for you (it should work according to the docs,
// but hasn't for me for some reason):
// import iterFrom from "core-js-pure/features/iterator/from";

let m = new Map();

m.set("13", 37);
m.set("42", 42);

const arr = iterFrom(m.values())
  .map((val) => val * 2)
  .toArray();

// prints "[74, 84]"
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone needs the typescript version:

```js
function* mapIter<T1, T2>(iterable: IterableIterator<T1>, callback: (value: T1) => T2) {
  for (let x of iterable) {
    yield callback(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could retrieve an iterator over the iterable, then return another iterator that calls the mapping callback function on each iterated element.

```
const map = (iterable, callback) => {
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
      return {
        next() {
          const r = iterator.next();
          if (r.done)
            return r;
          else {
            return {
              value: callback(r.value),
              done: false,
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// Arrays are iterable
console.log(...map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], (num) => 2 * num)); // 0 2 4 6 8
```

Comment: How would this look in typescript?

Comment: @Brian the same but just has types: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwDwBUA0BVAPgAoBLKAUwCcEAjAG3IC4YBJC6+87AnGYBOnRoJgAa2ZEAHsywBKNARh5ZzNlVoMMhBTADeAWABQMGJXJQArpTB6jJkwG0AygE84NEHQB0ZdVBCUALpE8gbG9iagkLC+1P6UaDCxGuTObh7eyfHBsgDcdhGm5lY2YYX2YOSSUCG24eWR4NCmiVkBXpXVIfn1DSQAZjBElF4AJuDksgUN9maW1qY9MybkdBDkdcuzxQtlW-YAbgIWTHwCQiKiw15HdCeyONP745XM-QLrj70zAL5Lyz8nhFAd8YCDgQUQX8jEYAPSwmAAQUo1BcEBgCDMSXYKSMUQgnnIXjoIAA5kQvJTEEgiA4AAy8ACMvAATLwAMy8AAsgV4RDAFjg8lQihZMAAVDABUK8jB4TA6TAxVyYAA2GAADiMQA)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [itiriri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itiriri) that implements array-like methods for iterables:

```
import { query } from 'itiriri';

let m = new Map();
// set map ...

query(m).filter([k, v] => k < 10).forEach([k, v] => console.log(v));
let arr = query(m.values()).map(v => v * 10).toArray();
```

Comment: Nice! This is how JS’s APIs should have been done. As always, Rust gets it right: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html

Comment: "As always, Rust gets it right" sure... There's a standardization proposal for all sort of helper functions for the iterator interface https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers You can use it today with corejs by importing the `from` fn from "core-js-pure/features/iterator" which returns the "new" iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-iterable

Works with all of iterables (Map, generator function, array) and async iterables.

```
const map = new Map();
...
console.log(fluent(map).filter(..).map(..));
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer from [MartyO256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843335/martyo256) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53159921/7895659), a refactored typescript approach could be the following one:

```
function mapIterator<TIn, TOut>(
  iterator: Iterator<TIn>,
  callback: (input: TIn) => TOut,
): Iterator<TOut> {
  return {
    next() {
      const result: IteratorResult<TIn> = iterator.next();

      if (result.done === true) {
        return result;
      } else {
        return {
          done: false,
          value: callback(result.value),
        };
      }
    },
  };
}

export function mapIterable<TIn, TOut>(
  iterable: Iterable<TIn>,
  callback: (input: TIn) => TOut,
): Iterable<TOut> {
  const iterator: Iterator<TIn> = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  const mappedIterator: Iterator<TOut> = mapIterator(iterator, callback);

  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => mappedIterator,
  };
}
```