# How to iterate a Map() object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Map() object that I need to iterate, so I can get the day of the week and a selected hour. The code below doesn't work, because `Object.keys(newFieldReservationPrice).forEach` is trying to loop a Map() object, which seems to make no sense. So, is there a better solution for this?

Here is the code below:

```
handlePriceInput = (e, hour, day) => {
let value = e.target.value

const newFieldReservationPrice = this.state.newFieldReservationPrice
console.log('newFieldReservationPrice', newFieldReservationPrice) // A Map();
let map;

if (!newFieldReservationPrice instanceof Map) {
  console.log('!== Map')
  console.log('newFieldReservationPrice is a Map()? inside if ()', newFieldReservationPrice)
  if (newFieldReservationPrice[day] && newFieldReservationPrice[day][hour]) {
      newFieldReservationPrice[day][hour] = Number(value)
  } 
} else {
  map = new Map();
  console.log('map object', Object.keys(newFieldReservationPrice)) // logs map object []

  Object.keys(newFieldReservationPrice).forEach(key => {
    console.log('key', key)
      map.set(key, new Map(Object.entries(newFieldReservationPrice[key])));
  }); // This doesn't work
  console.log('Am I a Map()? map', map)

  const aux = map.get(day)
  console.log('aux day', aux) // A Map()
  aux.set(hour, Number(value)) // Comes as undefined || Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
  console.log('aux set', aux) // A Map()

  map.set(day, aux);
  console.log('what do I have?', map)
  
}
const isReservationPrice = !newFieldReservationPrice instanceof Map ? newFieldReservationPrice : map
console.log('isReservationPrice', isReservationPrice)

this.setState({
  newFieldReservationPrice: isReservationPrice
})
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach
Search on google a bit before asking question

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135661/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-map-by-its-value/47136047#47136047. Not exact dupe so not marking as dupe though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using map() on an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885365/using-map-on-an-iterator)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Map`s provide three ways to get iterators for their contents:

- [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) - Iterates the keys in the map
- [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) - Iterates the values
- [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) - Iterates the key and values, giving you `[key, value]` arrays (this is the default)

[As Nina notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513801/157247), `Map`s also provide [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach), which loops through their contents giving the callback the value, key, and map as arguments.

Use the one appropriate for your use case. For instance, if you're trying to replace `Object.keys`, use `keys`. Similarly, if you want the entries in the map (I notice you use `Object.entries` at one point), use `entries` or the default iterator.

Note that in a few places in your code, you seem to be trying to index into the map using `[]`. That doesn't work for maps, you need to use `get`.

Here's a simple example of using the default iterator (which is also the one you get from `entries`):

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set(1, "one");   // Could also include these when calling
map.set(2, "two");   // the constructor but I wanted to
map.set(3, "three"); // avoid any confusion

for (const [key, value] of map) { // Using the default iterator (could be `map.entries()` instead)
    console.log(`The value for key ${key} is ${value}`);
}
```

---

Also note that you're breaking [one of React's rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) by setting new state based on existing state, but not using the callback version of `setState`. If you need to use existing state when setting new state, you **must** use the callback version:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    // ...use `prevState` values (*not* `this.state`!) to create an object with
    // the updates, then return the object...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You mean something like `map.set(key, new Map(Object.entries(newFieldReservationPrice.get(key))))` ?

Comment: @RCohen - What are you trying to do with `new Map(Object.entries(newFieldReservationPrice.get(key)))`?

Comment: Like you said, indexing [key] into the map doesn't work. So the idea here is something like: 

- monday:
     - 08:00: 10 (storing 10 in this day and hour)

Get the day and the hour, in this case is 08:00 to save a new value. With `newFieldReservationPrice.forEach` I iterate the hours

Comment: @RCohen - Yes, but why are you creating a Map from the result? But yes, I mean using `newFieldReservationPrice.get(key)` instead of `newFieldReservationPrice[key]`. It was the *rest* of that that doesn't make sense to me, since it assumes that the values stored in `newFieldReservationPrice` are not maps (because it uses `Object.entries`), but you're setting a Map as a value in `newFieldReservationPrice`.

Comment: This is because this is data that comes from DB as an object and I need to send it back as a Map. That is why I'm doing this. This is a way I found, maybe not the best one. @T.J Crowder

Comment: @RCohen - The problem is you'll end up with `newFieldReservationPrice` containing a mix of non-Map objects and Maps. Either convert them all to Maps on receipt before putting them in `newFieldReservationPrice`, or don't convert them to Maps in this operation.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I saw just now. @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 17):

You can iterate a `Map` object using `for of`:

```
for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

which is the same as iterating over the entries:

```
for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

As @Nina Scholz said, you can use `forEach` on the `Map` prototype ([doc MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach)):

```
myMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, with `Object.entries(newFieldReservationPrice).forEach` doesn't work for me. The same for `Object.keys(newFieldReservationPrice).forEach`

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Map#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) and iterate the `Map` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the spread operator to transform the `Map` into a normal `Array` and then have all the standard array methods:

```js
[...myMap]
  .map(([key, value]) => { /* transform to what you want */ })
  .forEach(x => /* iterate how you want */)
```