# Checking containment in set of lists in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code returns false. What am I doing wrong?

```
var s = new Set([[1,2], [2,3]])
s.has([2, 3])
false
```

Comment: JavaScript defines the equality of objects by their references, not their values. `[2,3] != [2,3]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize object equality for JavaScript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't compare objects. [2, 3] === [2, 3] gives false. So you can't find object in set.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to fix this, i.e. converting everything to string?

Comment: var s = new Set([String([1,2]), String([2,3])]);
s.has(String([2, 3])) 
will return true. If thats how you wanna use it.

Comment: @Alex Not everything in JavaScript can be converted to a string (functions for example), so that won't always work, but in this case it would since you're just storing numbers.

Comment: @Alex To be clear, functions do have a `toString` method, but `JSON.toString` removes functions from the output, which is what you'll probably want to use for deep comparison.