# Distinct Values using Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have been using

```
      <FormGroup>
        <Campaign
          campaignName={this.campaignName.bind(this)}
          campaignOptions={[...new Set(this.props.records.map(options => options.campaign))]}/>
      </FormGroup>
```

to get a unique array for a dropdown option, however I now need to pass an array with each object in it having a label and a value.

I have refactored the code as follows,

```
   <FormGroup>
        <Campaign
          campaignName={this.campaignName.bind(this)}
          campaignOptions={[...new Set(this.props.records.map(options => {
            return {value: options.campaign, label: options.campaign };
          }))]}/>
      </FormGroup>
```

...but the unique element is now not working (see below with duplicates). What am I doing wrong please?

The input array looks like...

```
    [
    1. 0:{_id: "zWTiLEjqrCKdxTvze", owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", company_ID: "1", campaign: "newevent", …}
    2. 1:{_id: "SkZzDMAWokFFYEycp", owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", company_ID: "1", campaign: "instagramlaunch", …}
    3. 2:{_id: "p4pychanC5Zw8iWAQ", owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC", company_ID: "1", campaign: "stuffinhere", …}
       … more in here including more than 1 object with instagram launch for example
    ]
```

Original approach resulted in Array of...

```
    0:"newevent"
    1:"sheffieldevent"
    2:"stuffinhere"
    3:”instagramlaunch"
    4:”anothertest"
    5:”yetanother"
```

now results in...

```
    0:{value: "newevent", label: "newevent"}
    1:{value: "sheffieldevent", label: "sheffieldevent"}
    2:{value: "stuffinhere", label: "stuffinhere"}
    3:{value: "instagramlaunch", label: "instagramlaunch"}
    4:{value: "instagramlaunch", label: "instagramlaunch"}
    5:{value: "instagramlaunch", label: "instagramlaunch”}
    6:{value: "anothertest", label: "anothertest”}
    7:{value: "yetanother", label: "yetanother"}
```

Comment: When you say is not working, what do you mean?

Comment: can  u create a snippet?

Comment: do you have always the same value for value and label?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I always want the same in value and label

Comment: @Adelin I have amended the initial question to reflect the problem... now have duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize object equality for JavaScript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set)

Comment: What templating language are you using. Add that to the tags.

Comment: @bhspencer added react tag thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using lodash...

```
    campaignOptions={_.uniqBy(this.props.records.map((options,index) => {return { value: index, label: options.campaign }}),'label')}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> new Set(this.props.records.map(options => {
>     return {value: options.campaign, label: options.campaign };
> }))
> ```

Does not work, because every new object is a unique object and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) works with all types. As result, you get all options, but not unique options.

If you have the same pattern as you want, you could render the set after collecting all values and build a new objects array out of the set.

```
var optionsSet = new Set(array.map(option => option.campaign)),
    options = Array.from(optionsSet, v => ({ value: v, label: v }));
```

Comment: Great thanks for your quick work Nina Scholtz. I am getting a "optionsSet is not defined" error