# JS - Using Set() in Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How can i use Set() in objects? I read the documentation, it works with values in array, but with objects it do not work. Why? I want to avoid duplicate items that has exacly the same values.

```
let nameList_one = [{ name: 'harry', id: 1 }, { name: 'john', id: 2 }, { 'name': 'trevor', id: 3  }]
let nameList_two = [{ name: 'harry', id: 1  }, { name: 'ron', id: 4  }, { name: 'jackson', id: 5  }]

let fullNameList = [...nameList_one , ...nameList_two ]

let filteredList = [...new Set(fullNameList)] // the output is the merge of two array, duplicating "harry".
```

**Output:**

> [{ name: 'harry', id: 1 }, { name: 'john', id: 2 }, { 'name': 'trevor', id: 3  }, { name: 'harry', id: 1  }, { name: 'ron', id: 4  }, { name: 'jackson', id: 5  }]

**Expected Output:**

> [{ name: 'harry', id: 1 }, { name: 'john', id: 2 }, { 'name': 'trevor', id: 3  }, { name: 'ron', id: 4  }, { name: 'jackson', id: 5  }]

Thanks!!

Comment: Two different objects will never be `===` to each other. Object comparison only involves the object's reference value; the property values don't matter.

Comment: You would probably need to prototype the function Set() or add a custom comparison method to your object type, as @Pointy said object comparison is done by reference which will not be equal.

Comment: Relevant info: [How to customize object equality for Javascript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set/29759699#29759699) - spoiler: "you can't" so you can't really use a Set for what you're trying to do.  It simply doesn't do what you're looking for and can't be customized to do it either.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Can you give me a way to solve this? So i understood that `Set()` will not work.

Comment: You can use `reduce`, something like `fullNameList.reduce((a, c) => {
 !a.find(v => v.id === c.id) && a.push(c);
    return a;
}, []);`

Comment: Hmm do i have to use a parameter to do the comparison? Just to confirm. =)

Comment: You'll need to decide what makes two objects the same and use that for the comparison inside the `find` function. I assumed that is the `id` property.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot. I will try doing with `reduce` and `find` methods. ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This doesn't work with objects because they are not same objects:

```
{ name: 'harry', id: 1 } !== { name: 'harry', id: 1 }
```

A way that may work is:

```
let filteredList = [...new Set(fullNameList.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);
```

It cannot be recommended, because it uses serialization where it's unnecessary. Serialization will destroy object instances that cannot be serialized, will ignore non-enumerable properties and won't handle circular references. Objects that have different property order won't be removed as duplicates. Their properties should be sorted first. In case there are nested objects, keys should be sorted recursively. This makes this approach impractical.

If the objects are identified by one or several fields, `Map` with serialized fields as map keys can be used:

```
let filteredList = [
  ...new Map(fullNameList.map(obj => [`${obj.id}:${obj.name}`, obj]))
  .values()
];
```

Comment: Converting an object to string representation. You're welcome.

Comment: we cannot use object to string representation because order of keys may be diffrent

Comment: @lalrishav I agree. I came across the same issue when I was trying to store stringified objects using Set data type in Redis. Same data returned for the same entity from Firebase was not equal when stringified just because the order of the properties was different.

Comment: @AlperGüven FWIW, the last time this problem occurred to me with Firebase, I used json-stable-stringify

Answer (score 8):

A nice way of doing this is to subclass `Set`.

```
class UniqueNameSet extends Set {
    constructor(values) {
        super(values);

        const names = [];
        for (let value of this) {
            if (names.includes(value.name)) {
                this.delete(value);
            } else {
                names.push(value.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you all the other methods/properties of `Set`, but adds the extra functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Each object is a pointer to a memory address, so even if the two objects have the same properties it wont be equal.
One way to do this would be using JSON.stringify and copare the stringified object.

Answer (score 0):

To get unique field of array of object, if you have an idea of the field, you can try this.

```js
const data = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'John'}, {name:'Bob'}];

const res =  data.reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr)=> {
  if(acc[1].indexOf(curr.name)==-1) {
      acc[1].push(curr.name);
      acc[0].push(curr)
  }
  return acc
}, [[],[]])[0]

console.log(res)

 //[{ name: "Bob" }, Object { name: "John" }]
```

Answer (score -2):

FOR CLARITY

```
const array = [
  {
    name: "Joe",
    age: 17,
  },
  {
    name: "Joe",
    age: 17,
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 35,
  }
];

let myArray = [];

for(let a = 0; a < array.length; a++){

   let string = JSON.stringify(array[a]);

   myArray.push(string)

};

const set = new Set(myArray);

let newArray = [];

set.forEach((element) => {

  const parsedData = JSON.parse(element);

  newArray.push(parsedData);

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to clarify?

Comment: Making it readable cause I saw one written on one line. Not all JS newbies will understand that

Comment: Consider adding formatting then, because the code written as plain text it is significantly less readable than formatted