# TypeScript: Map has key (object) not working

Tags: typescript, dictionary, equality

I'm having some troubles while checking if a map already has an object as key.

e.g.

```
const myMap: Map<MyObject1, MyObject2> = new Map<MyObject1, MyObject2>();
```

I also defined an equals function in MyObject1 class

```
equals(other: ThreatAgentMgm): boolean {
    return other.id === this.id;
}
```

but `myMap.has(myObject1)` is always false.
I read theat the has method is based on the === operator, should I define something else in MyObject1 class?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use any `equals()` method when comparing objects for equality.  Why don't you just make your map key the `id` field of `MyObject1` and then do `myMap.has(myObject1.id)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize object equality for JavaScript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set) which talks about `Set` and not `Map` but it's about the same issue: key equality

Comment: I'll need to pass this map as it is to another existing Java API, which will parse this JSON. So what are you saying is that it's not possible to use an object as a key for a map? Am I right?

Comment: Do you really mean "Java"?  And JSON only allows string keys.  Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You can use an object as a key for a map, but you need to index by the same exact object. If this doesn't meet your needs you can implement your own `Map`-like thing that accepts a key equality function.  But I don't understand your use case enough to give a more concrete suggestion.  If you want more information please update your question with more details and someone can help.

Comment: Yes, I mean the Java API expects a JSON having MyObject1 stringified as the key of the object. So I'd need to be able to use an object as the key of the map. Strange it's not possible such a simple thing as it is in Java.

Comment: Well, the object has the same values, just it's a different instance in time.

Comment: `Map` in JavaScript is not the same as `Map` in Java, and neither of those are JSON.  ‍♂️

Comment: You can still use the stringified object as key.

Comment: Objects in maps are same instance match only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since every JSON object in the end is just a string, I ended up using the JSON.stringify(myObject) as the key of the Map, and a couple of values (MyObject1, MyObject2) as the actual value. This way I'm able to get the desired value in time O(1) while keeping the key object available, without the need of parsing the JSON again or worst, retrieving it from the DB once again.