# ES6 Hashmap with 2 keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

JavaScript ES6 introduced `Map` implemented with hash table. Since hash table look up time is on average O(1), for random accessed data, `Map` seems to be a good choice for data storage.

However, JavaScript does not have data structures like `struct` in C++ that can be used as keys in the Map to enable "multiple keys mapping". The closest ones are Objects, but their instances do not equal to each other even if "contents are the same".

**If I want to save a 2D or 3D tile based game map using the `Map` type, is there a way to easily access the blocks given the coordinates?** Of course strings like `"1,2,3"` (representing x,y,z) would work, but is there a way that we can use integers as keys?

And if I must fall back to using assembled string coordinates, would the performance decrease a lot?

**EDIT:** I want to use a hash table because there may be "holes" in the maps and tiles may be created randomly in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: What is expected data structure? `[[1,2,3], ['value']]`?

Comment: @guest271314 I want to store tile objects in the world in a map like `{[1,2,3]: Object}`. They would contain tile information and geometries that I would want to get rendered by something like Three.js.

Comment: Not looking good for customizing the equality relation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set

Comment: Regarding your edit, How would a Map help? If the key is not set, you'll face the same with a Map, an Array or any Object.

Comment: @Kaiido I believe hash tables allow the creation of a key out of random, but Arrays would fill the void with null. Wouldn't that create wasted space?

Comment: No. `const a = []; a[42] = 'the answer';` will create a [sparse Array](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=sparse+array+definitive), its `length` property will be set to `43` but `a[0~41]` are untouched and definitely not the value `null`. Sparse Arrays may make some optimizations inefective, mostly when accessing from a loop, but since it seems you only do random-access, these optimizations would probably not kick in anyway, so you are just fine with an Array, even if all the slots are not being used.

Comment: @Kaiido You're right. I've just created https://jsperf.com/sparse-array-objects-and-maps/ and indeed, on FF Array and Object are the same and fastest. On Chrome, Array is the fastest and same as to FF.

Comment: @Kalido In my opinion a sparse array indicates a type error and should be avoided.

Comment: @reify glad you're not a js-engine then. (while your nickname would be a funny name for one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a performance test between storing in Array, and Nested Object as well as Object with string keys. The result is surprising to me. The fastest is Object with string keys.

https://jsperf.com/multiple-dimension-sparse-matrix

```
Array           OPS 0.48    ±5.19%     77% slower    //a[z][y][x]
Nested Object   OPS 0.51    ±16.65%    77% slower    //a[z][y][x]
String Object   OPS 2.96    ±29.77%    fastest       //a["x,y,z"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is just a multidimensional Array. If you are going to use only integer keys, there is absolutely no benefit to use a Map.

```js
const map = [];
for(let x=0; x<2; x++) {
  let xArr = [];
  map.push(xArr);
  for(let y=0; y<2; y++) {
    let yArr = [];
    xArr.push(yArr);
    for(let z=0; z<2; z++) {
      yArr.push(`${x},${y},${z}`);
    }
  }
}
console.log(map[1][1][0]);
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed [Daniels' performance test](https://jsperf.com/multiple-dimension-sparse-matrix/4) by adding the "Left shifting" case, where we left shift those numbers (as long as we don't extrapolate the `number` limits). I got the following results:

```
Array           OPS 0.90    ±4.68%     91% slower    //a[z][y][x]
Nested Object   OPS 0.86    ±3.25%     92% slower    //a[z][y][x]
String Object   OPS 3.59    ±16.90%    68% slower    //a["x,y,z"]
Left Shift      OPS 10.68   ±11.69%    fastest       //a[(x<<N1)+(y<<N2)+z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than joining the keys into a string like you mentioned (which is perfectly fine IMO), another option is to use multiple nested `Map`s. For example, for a 3d structure, accessing `1,2,3` (axes x, y, and z, let's say) could be done with

```
bigMap.get(1).get(2).get(3)
```

where the `bigMap` (containing the 3d structure) contains `Map` values for each y and z slice, and each of *those* has Map keys corresponding to each z slice, and each z-slice Map has values containing the information at each coordinate.

But while this is a *possibility*, your idea of an object or `Map` indexed by comma-joined coordinates is perfectly fine and probably more understandable at a glance IMO.

Remember that object property lookup is `O(1)` just like `Map` lookup - there's no performance hit if you use a single object (or `Map`) indexed by strings.

Comment: I don't know where I got the impression that objects aren't necessarily implemented with hash tables and may have been linked list or some other data types? But if the only difference of objects and Maps are whether the keys can be objects, then this works. It has been tested that string keys are much slower than number keys. I know it's not going to affect small projects, but I'm just wondering what's the fasted way to implement something like this.

Comment: Would a 3D array be a better alternative? `array3D[1][2][3] = obj`?

Comment: Sure, that works too. There are multiple fine options for this sort of situation

Comment: Well OP is concerned about says that Maps with string keys are slow and i wonder (without bothering to experiment and find out) if arrays (which are just objects) end up being faster with integer keys.

Comment: @glumplum Arrays use Strings too. But given how Arrays are optimized, I'd still bet on them if I saw them in a contests against Maps.