# How to create a Pair class that's equal in Set when each entry equals?

Tags: javascript, hashset

```
class Pair {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }
    // TODO ?
}
const set = new Set()
set.add(new Pair(1, 2))
```

How to make follow statement to return true?

```
set.has(new Pair(1, 2)) // -> false
```

(We can override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Pair` class in Java)

Comment: JavaScript does not support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Overriding the equality check is infeasible right now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759699/7803502

Instead, you can extend the `Set` class to create your own `PairSet`.

```js
class Pair {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this._x = x
    this._y = y
  }
  
  toString() {
    return [
      this._x,
      this._y,
    ].join(',')
  }
}

class PairSet extends Set {
  add(pair) {
    return super.add(pair.toString())
  }
  
  has(pair) {
    return super.has(pair.toString())
  }
  
  delete(pair) {
    return super.delete(pair.toString())
  }
}

(function test() {
  const set = new PairSet()
  set.add(new Pair(1, 2))
  console.log(set.has(new Pair(1, 2))) // true
  console.log(set.has(new Pair(2, 1))) // false
})()
```

Answer (score 4):

The references will only be equal if they point to the same value in memory - `new` will (by default) create a *new* object, which cannot be `===` to a separate one. I suppose one option would be to return an existing `x,y` Pair instance if it's been constructed earlier:

```js
const pairs = {};
function getMakePair(x, y) {
  const str = x + ',' + y;
  if (pairs[str]) {
    return pairs[str];
  }
  const pair = new Pair(x, y);
  pairs[str] = pair;
  return pair;

}
class Pair {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
}

const set = new Set()
set.add(getMakePair(1, 2))
console.log(set.has(getMakePair(1, 2)))
```

Or, if you wanted all action to be in the constructor, you can have the constructor explicitly create / return the instance, though it's a bit less clear IMO, and it's kind of odd to see:

```js
class Pair {
  constructor(x, y) {
    const str = x + ',' + y;
    if (Pair.pairs[str]) {
      return Pair.pairs[str];
    }
    const instance = Object.create(Pair.prototype);
    instance.x = x
    instance.y = y
    Pair.pairs[str] = instance;
    return instance;
  }
}
Pair.pairs = {};

const set = new Set()
set.add(new Pair(1, 2))
console.log(set.has(new Pair(1, 2)))
```

Of course, if you use a method like this to cache instances, you shouldn't mutate the `.x` / `.y` property of the instance, else the caching mechanism will harder to reason about. If you want that sort of *mutable* caching functionality, you might consider using `.find` on an array of instances instead.