# How does angular's selection model determine equality of two objects?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, selectionmodel

I'm trying to select pre-select some users in a table using Angular's selectionmodel. The call retrieving the users in the table and the call retrieving the already selected users are different so the actual objects are not the same.

I tried writing an equals method on the UserProfile class, this does not seem to change anything. Rewriting the code to use id's would fix the problem but i would like to have the selection model handling the actual objects instead of id's.

This is the code i'm using, but i hope my question is clear enough.

```
@Input() selected: UserProfile[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<UserProfile>(true, this.selected);
```

Comment: Could you add few more details?

Comment: Once you get the selected users, just replace them with the correcponding users that are in the table.

Comment: @Jb Thanks,that will fix the problem, There is no way to make the selection model compare two objects based on something like an equals method ?

Comment: I don't know material very much, but based on what I saw in the source code and the deocumentation, I don't think so.

Comment: @JBNizet I guessed so too. The selection model is angular specific though it does not come from the material libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectionModel` is implemented as a part of `@angular/cdk` library. The documentation can be found in the [Collections page](https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/overview) from Angular Material Documentation.

In the code we use the following import:

```js
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
```

The `SelectionModel` is build using the native Javascript`Set()` object, as can be found in the source [code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts):

```js
private _selection = new Set<T>();
```

The `Set` object lets you store **unique** values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

The implementation for `SelectionModel` checks if an item is contained in that set by using `Set.has` method.

---

What we need to consider first is that, in Javascript, two different instances of objects are always **not equal**:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const obj2 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
obj1 !== obj2; // => true
```

So, the following situation will arive:

```js
const mySet = new Set();
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
const obj2 = {a: 1, b: 2};

mySet.add(obj1);

mySet.has(obj1); // -> Output: true
mySet.has({a: 1, b: 2}); // -> Output: false
mySet.has(obj2); // -> Output: false

mySet.add(obj2)   // obj2 is referencing a different object, so the object will be added in the set

mySet.size; // -> Output: 2

mySet.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
// Output: {a: 1, b: 2}
// Output: {a: 1, b: 2}
```

More info about JS `Set()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

---

**UPDATE (27.03.2023) - Angular 14+**

From **Angular 14**, the `SelectionModel` supports a **custom `compareWith` function** - a function optionally passed in order to customize how the `Selection Model` uniquely identifies the items:

```js
compareWith: (o1: T, o2: T) => boolean
```

https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/api#SelectionModel

So, we can compare our objects in the selection model by using their attributes (eg: `name` attribute). The compare functions returns a boolean:

```js
interface IPeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  symbol: string;
  ...
}

customCompareFn = (o1: IPeriodicElement, o2: IPeriodicElement) =>
    o1.name === o2.name;
```

Initialize our `SelectionModel` as follows:

```js
public selection = new SelectionModel<IPeriodicElement>(
    true,
    this.initialSelection,
    true,
    (o1: IPeriodicElement, o2: IPeriodicElement) =>
    o1.name === o2.name;
  );
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntmyut?file=src/app/selection-example/selection-example.component.ts

---

For **Angular <=13**:

There is no method to override the comparison method in the `Set` object, so I've wrote my own implementation of the `SelectionModel` - `SelectionModelImmutableJS` by using the very popular library called [immutable-js](https://immutable-js.com/). The implementation was inspired by the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56353815/1135971).

To simplify, by using `immutable-js`, we'll have the following situation:

```js
const { Map, Set } = require('immutable');
const map1 = Map({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const map2 = Map({ a: 1, b: 2 });

map1 !== map2; // => true, two different instances are not reference-equal
map1.equals(map2); // true, but are value-equal if they have the same values
const set = Set().add(map1);
set.has(map2); // true, because these are value-equal
```

The code for the Selection Model is a little bit too large and I will not post it inline - it can be found in the working demo.

In the app we'll use:

```js
import { SelectionModelImmutableJS } from './selection-model-immutable';

.....


public selection = new SelectionModelImmutableJS<IPeriodicElement>(
    true,
    this.initialSelection
  );
```

The full working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wnvohl