# Select distinct object from a list without using foreach loop in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a source list of objects of 4 properties with some duplicate values, want to select distinct objects of 2 properties without using a foreach loop.

Source list:

```
let Students=  [
 {Id: 1, Name: 'A', Class: 'I', Subject: 'Math'},
 {Id: 2, Name: 'B', Class: 'II', Subject: 'Bengali'},
 {Id: 1, Name: 'A', Class: 'I', Subject: 'Science'},
 {Id: 2, Name: 'B', Class: 'II', Subject: 'English'}
];
```

I want an output list like:

```
[
  {Id: 1, Name: 'A'},
  {Id: 2, Name: 'B'}
]
```

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Solution to return Distinct data for Object Array

`this.studentOptions = this.students.filter((item, i, arr) => arr.findIndex((t) => t.Id=== item.Id) === i);`

Answer (score 1):

This solution produces the result in the form you asked for. Objects need to be *stringified* before they get added to the `Set`, otherwise equal ones are not recognized (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759699/2358409).

```
const set = new Set(Students.map(s => JSON.stringify({ Id: s.Id, Name: s.Name })));
const identifiers = Array.from(set).map(i => JSON.parse(i));
```

If you want to avoid *stringify*, you can do the following.

```
const set = new Set(Students.map(s => s.Id + ';' + s.Name));
const identifiers = Array.from(set).map(i => ({ Id: i.split(';')[0], Name: i.split(';')[1] }));
```

The same can be done in a cleaner way using `Map`.

```
const map = new Map();
Students.map(s => map.set(s.Id, { Id: s.Id, Name: s.Name }));
const identifiers = Array.from(map.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're in the world of typescript, make use of the *types* provided by it. Create a class `Student`, this will be useful for easier management of your objects.

```
export class Student {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Class?: string;
  Subject?: string;

  constructor(Id: number, Name: string) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
  }
}
```

Create an array to hold the distinct objects:

```
distinctStud: Student[] = [];
```

Now you may:

```
from(this.Students)
   .pipe(
      map(std => new Student(std.Id, std.Name)),
      distinct(x => x.Id && x.Name)
    )
   .subscribe(val => this.distinctStud.push(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.from(new Set(yourArray.map((item: any) => item.id)))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this like newbie way

```
    let st=[];
Students.map((data)=>{
 let isExist=!!st.find((data2)=>{ 
 return data2.Id==data.Id});
if(!isExist)
  st.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **rxjs**'s **map** and **distinct** operators we can achieve this. Please check the code below

```js
   var Students=  [
 {Id: 1, Name: 'A', Class: 'I', Subject: 'Math'},
 {Id: 2, Name: 'B', Class: 'II', Subject: 'Bengali'},
 {Id: 1, Name: 'A', Class: 'I', Subject: 'Science'},
 {Id: 2, Name: 'B', Class: 'II', Subject: 'English'}
];

  const sourceObj = from(Students);
  const mappedObj=sourceObj.pipe(map((x)=>{return {Id: x.Id, Name:x.Name}}));
  const distictObj = mappedObj.pipe(distinct((x)=>x.Id && x.Name));

  console.log(distictObj.subscribe(x=>console.log(x)));
```

Please check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkduva).

Thanks.