# Set.prototype.has() returns false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES6 Sets. I am trying to add an array and check its existence in the set but it is returning me false. Here is the code I am working on.

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(1);
set.add([2, 3]);
set.add([2, 3]);

console.log(set);
console.log(set.has([2, 3]));
```

Please can someone explain this behaviour.

Comment: `[2, 3] !== [2, 3]`. Try `let x = [2, 3]; set.add(x); set.has(x);`

Comment: its comparing the references of the objects, not the value of the object.

Comment: @ASDFGerte can you please suggest me why ?

Comment: @DanielA.White Please post an answer as to why

Comment: thats just the way it works.

Comment: @BantiKumar if you have `var x = [1];` and `var y = [1];`, then `x` does not equal `y` even though they have the same array value, and that's because they have different references (kind of like pointers).

Comment: Assume you have two red apples. They are both red apples, but you still have two. It's the same here, you added one `[2, 3]`, then another, then ask if it contains yet another that you created just in that call, passed as argument. You can even see, that `set.size` is `3`, from the three (different) things you added.

Comment: Useful related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `Set` contains an object, `.has()` determines whether or not the Set contains the same exact object, not whether the Set contains an object that contains the same data as some other object.  It has to contain the same object.

So, `.has(someObj)` or `.has(someArray)` only returns `true` if that actual object is in the `Set`.  It does not compare to see if a similar object with the same values/properties are in the `Set`, only if the actual object itself is in the `Set`.

It works similar to comparing two objects with `===` as in `obj1 === obj2`.

If you wanted something with features similar to a Set that would tell you if it had any other object matching the current one, then you'd have to write a different collection yourself and implement your own comparison algorithm.  This is not how a `Set` or a `Map` work.

You can see some other discussion of a similar topic here: [How to customize object equality for JavaScript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set/29759699#29759699)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const set = new Set();
const array = [ 2, 3 ];
set.add(1);
set.add(array);
set.add(array);

console.log(set);
console.log(set.has(array));
```

Set#has checks for object identity, not deep equality. This is different than, say, Java's HashMap, which uses Object#equals in the background.

Answer (score 0):

just because primitive value is immutable
and object is reference (such as array, function etc) and reference object is mutable

see example
`let x = 1;` // orginal
`let y = x;` // copy

`y = y + x;` // modifing

`console.log(x);` // return 1
`console.log(y);` // return 2

Note: example above is not impacting in original value

// reference object

`let x = [1];` // orginal
`let y = x;`  // copy

`y.push(2);`

`console.log(x);` // return [1, 2]
`console.log(y);` // return [1, 2]

note: example above is impact in all

// comparison

`let a = [1];`
`let b = [2];`

`console.log(a === b);` // return false
`console.log(a !== b);`

Note: example above to know reason go to this link - [https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/#:~:text=The%20simple%20rule%20of%20passing,Every%20single%20time](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20simple%20rule%20of%20passing,Every%20single%20time).