# Angular - Remove Duplicate Objects from an Array using set

Tags: arrays, typescript

I need to remove all duplicate objects from my array. I know I can do it by using filter or reduce, but I want to use set instead since (if it works) it should be the shortes and cleanest option.

**origionalArray**

```
[{type: "A", label: "A", department: "C"},
{type: "B", label: "B", department: "C"},
{type: "B", label: "B", department: "C"}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{type: "A", label: "A", department: "C"},
{type: "B", label: "B", department: "C"}]
```

**I tried:**

```
distinctArray = new Set(origionalArray);
```

But it returns origionalArray. So my guess is it compares the objects by reference. In java i would override the equals method. But as far as I can find it online this can't be done in TS.

Any ideas how I can get this done? Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759699/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicate from array in TS by using this.

```
const expected = new Set();
const unique = arr.filter(item => !expected.has(JSON.stringify(item)) ? expected.add(JSON.stringify(item)) : false);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me the following error: ''TS2568: Type 'Set<{}>' is not an array type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.'' Adding **"downlevelIteration": true** to my tsconfig does not solve the problem. So I tried to use **Array.from(new Set(origionalArray)**. Then the error disapears, but I still get the origionalArray instead of the reduced Array.

Comment: ok, previous code works only for strings. i've update the answer for object level checks.

Comment: arr is your original array which is being filtered to remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect. I accepted this as the correct awnser :)

Comment: glad it helps you. happy coding :)