# interface unique value in item of array using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am gradually learning React using TypeScript.
I constantly face the problem of describing objects so that ESLint can prompt me.
I am trying to describe an object in an array so that its field `name` was with a unique value from a possible enumeration `IKeyNameColumns` .
To make it easier for me to understand what I mean, I'd better give an example:

```
type IKeyNameColumns = 'name' | 'status' | 'type' | 'age'

interface IListColumns {
  columns: Array<{
    title: string
    name: IKeyNameColumns // need only one uniq value of IKeyNameColumns 
  }>
}
```

I understand that it is rather done with the help of Generics and rather has something to do with the collection `Set`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no way to enforce that at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this using arrays, but arrays are the same as objects.

I would approach your probleme as follow:

```js
type IKeyNameColumns = 'name' | 'status' | 'type' | 'age'

interface IColumn {
  title: string
}

type IListColumns = { [K in IKeyNameColumns]: IColumn }

const listColumns: IListColumns = {
  name: { title: "Name Title"},
  status: { title: "Status Title"}
}
```

This way you cannot duplicate keys, nor you can add unknown `IKeyNameColumns`. ([see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkg0hEA5AhgWwgYQPYBsCuaAdgM5QC8UA5EehFVAD7UnArD4kPNWiTfUUAc3oAoUQEsiwCACcAZigDG0GDgLEoAb1FQowCcFwQAXFFaypQ0QF9xfVQBkJrdYVIVtUANpwoU2ARkOjdiEgBdMzU8dyg7USVsUmAoXBdgUNIo51cYsM8dPVoMMy19Q2MzACJUDCgAFQqIKpsAGl1zNg4SUvKjUygqgGUuzgamlva9VnZOXoN%206pHZskb%20yY78UnwwMGxZGQATeabqgFUkIbOABWuAeQAleoBRABEW2yA))

If you need to iterate on `listColumns` you can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution looks reasonable and in fact, this is the only way to achieve safe column identification. In fact, I also considered this option and came to the conclusion that when adding or changing a field during iteration in an imperative or functional way, it is possible to accidentally re-sort the columns. Rather, I still need to add the sort field.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand you try to tell `IListColumns` that the `columns` array is not allowed to have 2 elements with the same `name` property.

As far as I know that is not possible with generics and should be solved with a `Set`, which you also mentioned in your question.

That leads to the next problem, `Set` has, as far as I know, no possibility to define a comparator, which would indicate a equalness in case of equal `name` property and instead always check the whole object.

The same is also discussed here: [How to customize object equality for JavaScript Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set/29759699#29759699)