# Using Set in javascript to store a tuple

Tags: javascript, set

I have a scenario in which I have to store a tuple (x,y,z) in a set. As javascript doesn't have a tuple, I decided to store it in the set like [1,2,0], but it allows me to add this same 
 element again to the set and show the size as 2, whereas ideally, it should not add it. How can I achieve default Set behavior or some alternate way to represent the above information

Comment: consider JSON serialization.

Comment: This may provide a bit of background on why it allows the same tuple value:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759480/how-to-customize-object-equality-for-javascript-set

Comment: Every array is a distinct object from other arrays, even if they contain the exact same contents. The Set mechanism only cares about object identity, not content.

Comment: so there is nothing like a set in the same way we have in other languages like python and java