# HashMap in TypeScript with custom object

Tags: javascript, hashmap, es6-map

### Introduction

I am currently work in project that I need to save the score of each user.
For this I used a `Map<User, number>` to represent it.

### Problematic

If I create map with a user named john:

```js
let myMap: Map<User, number> = new Map();
myMap.set(new User("John","Hasherman"), 0);
```

And if I want to set John Hasherman’s score to 1 (voluntarily using a new instance and not the one previously used), with this code:

```js
myMap.set(new User("John","Hasherman"), 1);
```

But TypeScript create a new element inside myMap.

### Question

So my question is, do you know if it’s possible to customize the comparator used inside the map? like Java when defining `hashCode()` and `equals(o Object)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding the equality function of a Javascript Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051344/overriding-the-equality-function-of-a-javascript-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a way for the User to expose functionality that will identify a particular user, perhaps by name, or perhaps by a more unique ID. Either way, a Map where each user is the key isn't very suited to the job, but it's possible.

```
class User {
    public first: string;
    public last: string;
    constructor(first: string, last: string) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
}

const myMap: Map<User, number> = new Map();
myMap.set(new User("John","Hasherman"), 0);

// to set John's value to 1:
const foundJohn = [...myMap.keys()].find(
    obj => obj.first === 'John' && obj.last === 'Hasherman'
);
if (foundJohn) {
    myMap.set(foundJohn, 1);
}
```

It's somewhat convoluted. I'd suggest considering a different data structure if possible.

Comment: Indeed, unlike Java here the map is not very appropriate.

Comment: Yes, a different data structure is the right call here, especially since you lose the [O(1) complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33611509/1426891) of Set and Map access and get array-scan O(n) complexity instead. This frequently defeats the purpose of using Set and Map, due to the uncertain performance.