# Can the JS equality operators (like ===) work with embind types?

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Suppose I have some Emscripten bindings like so:

```
class_<MyNode>("MyNode")
    .constructor<>()
    .function("getParentNode", &MyNode::parentNode, allow_raw_pointers());
```

When I run the following code in JS, I get `false`, but I want it to be `true`:

```
node.getParentNode() === node.getParentNode()
```

I'm guessing this is because Emscripten is wrapping the result of each function call in a new JS object, even though the JS objects point to the same underlying C++ object.

That is, is there some trick in Emscripten for JS `===` or `==` to return true with bound types that have the same underlying raw pointer values?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. From [the MDN docs on the strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality):

> If both operands are objects, return `true` only if they refer to the same object.

You might be interested in [this SO thread asking on how to "overload" the equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10539938/11107541)