# Doing an operator (==) equality check in js

Tags: javascript

I have the following class:

```
class Coord {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }
    equals(b) { // how to add this method?
        return true;
    }
}

let p1 = new Coord(1,2);
let p2 = new Coord(1,2);
console.assert(p1 == p2, 'points are not equal');
```

Is there a method I can add into the class such that `p1 == p2` in the above? I'd like to do it within the class and not something like a `JSONStringify` approach.

The equivalent in python I would do would be:

```
class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, o):
        return (self.x == o.x) and (self.y == o.y)

p1 = Coord(1,2);
p2 = Coord(1,2);
print (p1==p2)
# True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override the Equivalence Comparison in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539938/override-the-equivalence-comparison-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative

```
class Coord {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }

    valueOf(b) { 
        return `${x},${y}`
    }
}

let p1 = new Coord(1,2);
let p2 = new Coord(1,2);
console.assert(p1.valueOf() == p2.valueOf(), 'points are not equal');
```

Comment: @mathieu -- I see, I think that's the closest approach. But so in modern js there is no way to override the bare `==` check?

Comment: Nope, not at the moment.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler -- It's kinda an anti-pattern to override natively available methods like `valueOf`. It can lead to bugs in code. The better approach would be to have a non-native method for the same.

Answer (score 2):

There you go :)

```js
class Coord {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }
    
    print() {
        console.log('(' + `%c${this.x}` + ', ' + `%c${this.y}` + '%c)', "color:red", "color: blue", "color: black");
    }
    
    equals(b) {
        return (this.x===b.x && this.y===b.y);
    }
}

let p1 = new Coord(1,2);
let p2 = new Coord(1,2);
let p3 = new Coord(1,3);
let p4 = new Coord(4,2);

console.assert(p1.equals(p2), 'p1 and p2 are not equal');
console.assert(p1.equals(p3), 'p1 and p3 are not are not equal');
console.assert(p1.equals(p4), 'p1 and p4 points are not equal');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare two instances of the `Coord` class you will not be able to do that within the class itself. How you have it set up seems like a decent approach. You could also compare the coordinate values before creating the class.

Comment: I see, so there's no way to override the `==` operator, like you could do in python with [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) ?

Comment: No way no, but you could do `p1.valueOf() == p2.valueOf()`

Answer (score 0):

One option is using lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

Example from lodash documentation:

```js
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };
 
_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true
 
object === other;
// => false
```