# Call function if two arrays are identical with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question regarding using jQuery to compare 2 arrays. I have two arrays, and I need to call a function only if they are exactly identical (same size, elements, order).

For example, given these two arrays:

```
a['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven', 'eight','nine'];
b['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven', 'eight','nine'];
```

If these two are arrays are identical and in the same order, do:

```
do  function{};
```

Comment: this site is to help you get things done, not doing things for you.

Comment: You'll have to loop and compare them directly.

Comment: Here is an answer for a similar question in StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little type coercion avoids the loop:

```
var myarray=["Joe", "Bob", "Ken"];
    var myarray2=["Joe", "Bob", "Ken"];
    var myarray3=["Joe", "Beb", "Ken"];
if(myarray == ""+myarray2){alert("something");}
if(myarray == ""+myarray3){alert("something else");}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nY7Pk/

Answer (score 2):

The [isEqual method in underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) may be helpful if you don't want to handle the details yourself.

Comment: hey thanks but I have to implement the solution using only current version of jQuery. I'll keep it in mind though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven', 'eight','nine'];
var b=['zero','one','two','four','three','five','six','seven', 'eight','nine'];
var difference = [];

jQuery.grep(a, function(element, index) {
    if(a[index]!=b[index])
       difference.push(element);
});

if(difference.length>0){
   alert("Do something");
}
```

​

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not work for arrays that have complex values, such as other arrays or objects.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using plain JavaScript - which you can use alongside jQuery.

```
if (a.length === b.length) {
    var isMatch = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
            isMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isMatch) {
        alert('It was all identical');
    }
}
```

If you want to allow juggling in your matches, you can change `!==` to `!=`.

`!==` will return false if the type or the value doesn't match.

`!=` will return false after juggling the types if the value doesn't match.