# JavaScript - How to cross-compare an array to itself

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var myObjArray = [{city: 'milwaukee', state: 'wi'}, 
                  {city:'madison', state: 'wi'}, 
                  {city:'greenbay', state: 'wi'}, 
                  {city:'madison', state: 'wi'}];
```

How would I compare the array against itself to find duplicates.
(Note: I need to keep the duplicates, so maybe I could add a property to the object as a flag).

Comment: See this post in comparing objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Do what @Niels suggested (there's also this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and then just loop through your array and compare the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var bucket = {};
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    var item = array[i];
    var hash = JSON.stringify(item); //or some a hashing algorithm...
    var prev = bucket[hash];
    if(prev) {
        prev.duplicate = item.duplicate = true;
    } else {
        bucket[hash] = item 
    }   
}
```

Or same without dependending upon `JSON.stringify`:

```
var markDuplicates = function(array, hashFunc) {
    var bucket = {};
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var item = array[i];
        var hash = hashFunc(item);
        var prev = bucket[hash];
        if(prev) {
            prev.duplicate = item.duplicate = true;
        } else {
            bucket[hash] = item 
        }   
    }
    return array;
};

markDuplicates(yourArray, function(item) { return item.city + item.state; });
```

Comment: You don't want to `Stringify` it, not all browsers support this yet + You don't know the property order. This can also be different per browser.

Comment: @Niels, good points. In my defense I live in a world where JSON.strinfigy is granted. Added an alternative implementation with a safer hash function.

Comment: Yeah at my job we still support IE7-8, so this isn't an option for us yet =(.