# Compare a String Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a code where there is a string to be compared with the variable array. Here if it is found, I need to alert that the match is found. Below is my code.

Here I'm comparing a single string with the array of strings. I'm not comparing two different js arrays.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTable() {
            var dataTerm = document.getElementById('Select2').value;
            var cancellations = new Array();
            var changeInfo = new Array();
            var idq = new Array();
            var others = new Array();
            var replace = new Array();
            var moreInfo = new Array();
            var salesRep = new Array();
            var custReq = new Array();
            var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
            myTableDiv.border = "1";


            var variablesArray = new Array[cancellations, changeInfo, idq, others, replace, moreInfo, salesRep, custReq];

            for (var i = 0; i < variablesArray.length; i++) {
                if (dataTerm == variablesArray[i].value) {
                    alert("matched at" + variablesArray[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Renewal/Product #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Product Title</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text2" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Account #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text3" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Product Code</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text4" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Invoice #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text5" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Suspended Date</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text6" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Shipment / To #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text7" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Term Inc/ Dec</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text8" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Tracking #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text9" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Qty Inc/ Dec From</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text10" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Unit #</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text11" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Qty Inc/ Dec To</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Text12" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Billing Address</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text13" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">E-mail ID</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Name</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input id="Text14" type="text" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style5">Request Type</td>
            <td>
                <select id="Select2" name="D2">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                    <option value="Cancellations">Cancellations</option>
                    <option value="Changing Information">Changing Information</option>
                    <option value="Increase or Decrease Quantity/Term/Users">Increase or Decrease Quantity/Term/Users</option>
                    <option value="Others">Others</option>
                    <option value="Replacement">Replacement</option>
                    <option value="Fore more information">Fore more information</option>
                    <option value="Contacting Sales rep">Contacting Sales rep</option>
                    <option value="Requesting Customer">Requesting Customer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3" colspan="4">
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="addTable()" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style4" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style5" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="height: 420px" id="myDynamicTable">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here in my case, to my surprise nothing happens when I click on the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: it's `new Array()`, not `new Array[]`... Maybe you should open your console and clear all the syntax errors in the code

Comment: Why do you need a loop of `variablesArray` in the first place? You already have the data for the array to test against without needing a loop

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var cancellations = new Array();
> ```

Here you create a (new) empty array.

> ```
> var variablesArray = new Array(cancellations, changeInfo, idq, others, replace, moreInfo, salesRep, custReq);
> ```

Here you create an array containing several empty arrays.

> ```
> if (dataTerm == variablesArray[i].value)
> ```

The expression `variablesArray[i]` will evaluate to one of the empty arrays that you put in this array.  The expression `.value` will evaluate to `undefined` because arrays don't have an attribute named `value`.  Since the string you have is not equal to undefined, the condition is never true.

Comment: @gothical Yeah, I overlooked that syntax error in the OP's code that I quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: when you get `dataTerm`, it's a string value. You are comparing `dataTerm`with an element in `variablesArray`, these elements are Arrays (once you initialized then with `new Array()`. You can't compare so different things.

Another topic: don't use square brackets in

`new Array[cancellations, changeInfo, idq, others, replace, moreInfo, salesRep, custReq];`

`Array` is a function, use parenthesis.

`new Array(cancellations, changeInfo, idq, others, replace, moreInfo, salesRep, custReq);`

Try this in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < variablesArray.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < variablesArray[i].length; j++){
        if (dataTerm == variablesArray[i][j].value) {
            alert("matched at" + variablesArray[i][j].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed, but there is no change :-(

Comment: What did you change? The array definition or the loop? Please, post the new code here.