# Why does componentDidUpdate() create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've stored `url` and a `token` in `state` in `Parent` component. I'm passing an `url` and a `token` as `props` from parent `Component` to child `Component`. However, if there is some event in parent `Component`, `setState()` is triggered and as a result, `componentDidUpdate()` of child `Component` gets executed.
As `componentDidUpdate()` was causing an infinite loop *(as it triggers setState() inside child component)*, I've placed condition. But this does not prevent the error.
Child Component ie `DisplayRevenue` is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ListData from './listdata.js'
var axios = require('axios');

class DisplayRevenue extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[], url:"" }
  console.log(this.props.url);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadRevenue(this.props.url, this.props.token);
 }

  componentDidUpdate(){    //creates infinite loop
  //  console.log(this.props.url);
    this.loadRevenue(this.props.url, this.props.token);
  }

  setData(data){
    //if(this.state.url != this.props.url){
    if(this.state.data != data.data){
      console.log(data.data);                     //(1)
  //    console.log(this.state.url);              //(2)
      this.setState(data:data);             
      console.log(this.state.data);               //(3)
  //    console.log(this.props.url);              //(4)
    }     //(1) & (3) yields exactly same value so does (2) & (4)
  }

  loadRevenue(url,token){
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
     .then( (response) => {
    //   console.log(response.data);
       this.setData(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Revenue "+error);
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListData data={this.state.data}/>
    );
  }
};

export default DisplayRevenue;
```

Parent Component ie MonthToDate is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import DisplayRevenue from './displayRevenue'
var axios = require('axios');

class MonthToDate extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:null,
      url:"http://localhost:3000/api/monthtodate"
    }
    //console.log(this.props.location.state.token);
  }

  groupBySelector(event){
    if ((event.target.value)==="invoice"){
      this.setState({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/monthtodate"})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="customer") {
      this.setState({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/monthtodate?group-by=customerNumber"})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="month") {
      this.setState({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/invoices?group-by=month"})
    } else {
      this.setState({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/monthtodate"})
    }
    console.log(this.state.url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <select onChange={(event)=>this.groupBySelector(event)}>
        <option value="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</option>
        <option value="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</option>
        <option value="month">GROUP BY MONTH</option>
      </select>
        <DisplayRevenue url={this.state.url} token={this.props.location.state.token}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MonthToDate;
```

- What am I missing?
- Also, after I've received the `url` in the child component I want to render different component based on that `url`. For example `<ListData />` component can handle only one type of `url`. How can I render another component within `render()` based on the `url` type??

Comment: Why do you have a axios request in the componentDidUpdate, that axios request will be executed on every render and further because it does a setState it goes on loop

Comment: You are setting state this causes axios call and that sets state and that causes component to update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state and that causes update and that sets state....

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri where is `setState()` inside axios?? axios is calling `setData()` which checks equality before executing `setState()`

Comment: You are calling `this.setData(response.data);` in axios success callback, that has setState

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri setData() also have `if(this.state.data != data.data)` condition. See the commented portions those value's are equal. Then also it is getting executed.

Comment: @bennygenel axios doesn't directly do `setState()` instead it calls `setData()` which checks for equality before executing `setState()`

Comment: Whats the response data? is it a string?

Comment: @bennygenel `response.data` is array of json objects

Comment: You can't just compare 2 object arrays with equality operators. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27212/2315280) on how to do it  and please check [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) event of React

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are calling an ajax call in `componentDidUpdate`, and you set the state on the callback, that will trigger another call and update which will call the ajax request again and callback will set state again and so on.
Your condition in `setData`:

```
if(this.state.data != data.data)
```

will always return true as objects are reference type and can't be compared, no matter what data returned from the ajax call it will always be a different object and will return `true` in your condition.
Example:

```js
var obj1 = {a:1}
var obj2 = {a:1}

console.log(obj1 != obj2); // returns true
```

What you can do, is compare [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) values inside the two objects.
For example:

```
if(this.state.data.id != data.id) // id could be a string or a number for example
```

**EDIT**
Another thing i forgot to mention which may not relate to your problem directly but should be enforced, **Never** do ajax requests inside `componentWillMount` or the `constructor` for that matter, as the render function will be invoked before your ajax request will finish. you can read about it in the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount).
Ajax requests should be invoked in `componentDidMount` [life cycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead.

**EDIT #2**
Another thing that can be helpful, in the `MonthToDate` render function you are passing a new instance of a function on each render (which may cause a performance hit)

```
<select onChange={(event)=>this.groupBySelector(event)}>
```

Try changing it to this (the event will be passed automatically to the handler):

```
 <select onChange={this.groupBySelector}>
```

You would also need to bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:null,
      url:"http://localhost:3000/api/monthtodate"
    }
    //console.log(this.props.location.state.token);

    this.groupBySelector = this.groupBySelector.bind(this); // binds this to the class
  }
```

Comment: Ok. Then please tell me what should I do?

Comment: I've also tried comparing two strings `if(this.state.url != this.props.url)` (Commented in the code) it doesn't work either. Although during infinite loop, when I log their o/p they are exactly same.

Comment: @Sag1v What alternative from calling ajax in `componentWillMount` do you suggest? I am doing this most of the time but I am not sure that it is the proper way. Perhaps you could include it to your answer too

Comment: @JDHrnnts ajax requests should be invoked in `componentDidMount` (answer updated). [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)