# How to render a component (Immediately) from two different input events?

Tags: reactjs

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237553/why-only-one-component-is-re-rendering-immediately-and-other-is-not) SO post.

I have two event handler (`<select onChange={this.groupBySelector}>` and `<DateSelector dateOnSelect={this.urlProducer}/>`) in a single class `QuarterToDate`.
In the above mentioned class, user is provided with two features ie A Select Option and A Date Selector. Both of this event triggers `this.setState()`. But, the component is re-rendering in only one of them ie `<select onChange={this.groupBySelector}>`. What should I do?

QuarterToDate class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import DisplayInvoice from './displayInvoice';
import DisplayCustomer from './displayCustomer';
import DisplayMonth from './displayMonth';
import DateSelector from './dateSelector';

var axios = require('axios');

class QuarterToDate extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:null,
      invoiceType:'invoice',
      urlInvoices:'',
      urlCustomer:'',
      isDateSet:false
    }
    //console.log(this.props.location.state.token);
     this.groupBySelector = this.groupBySelector.bind(this);
  }

  groupBySelector(event){
    if ((event.target.value)==="invoice"){
      this.setState({invoiceType:'invoice'})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="customer") {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'customer'})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="month") {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'month'})
    } else {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'invoice'})
    }
  }

  urlProducer = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      urlInvoices: ("http://localhost:3000/api/invoices"+date),
      urlCustomer: ("http://localhost:3000/api/invoices"+date+"&group-by=customerNumber"),
      isDateSet: true
    }, () => {console.log(this.state.urlCustomer);});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //<DateSelector />
      <div>
      <DateSelector dateOnSelect={this.urlProducer}/>
      <select onChange={this.groupBySelector}>
        <option value="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</option>
        <option value="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</option>
        <option value="month">GROUP BY MONTH</option>
      </select>
        <GroupBy token={this.props.location.state.token} invoiceType={this.state.invoiceType} isDateSet={this.state.isDateSet} urlInvoices={this.state.urlInvoices} urlCustomer={this.state.urlCustomer}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default QuarterToDate;

function GroupBy(props) {
  if (props.invoiceType=='invoice') {
    return <DisplayInvoice token={props.token} url={(props.isDateSet) ? (props.urlInvoices) : "http://localhost:3000/api/quartertodate"}/>;
  } else if (props.invoiceType=='customer') {
    console.log(props.isDateSet);
    return <DisplayCustomer token={props.token} url={(props.isDateSet) ? (props.urlCustomer) : "http://localhost:3000/api/quartertodate?group-by=customerNumber"}/>;
  } else if (props.invoiceType=='month') {
    return <DisplayMonth token={props.token}/>;
  }
}
```

Code for `DateSelector` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Moment from 'moment';

class DateSelector extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate:"",
      endDate:""
    }
  }

  dateHandler = (event) => {
    this.props.dateOnSelect("?startDate="+Moment(this.state.startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    +"&endDate="+Moment(this.state.endDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
  }

  startDateOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({startDate: event.target.value});
  }

  endDateOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({endDate: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        START DATE<input type="date" id="startDate" value={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.startDateOnChange}/>
        END DATE<input type="date" id="endDate" value={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.endDateOnChange}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.dateHandler}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DateSelector;
```

Comment: Re-post your related code in full.

Comment: @Chris I just did. kindly let me know if I need to post anything else.

Comment: Can you kindly share the code for your ```<DateSelector  />``` component, so that the community can help you more.

Comment: @AdeelImran I just did.

Comment: In your ```this.dateHandler``` func try doing event.preventDefault(); then try consoling that the data is being passed or not in that function.

Comment: @AdeelImran it is passing data to `urlProducer` of `QuarterToaDate` class successfully. I've logged it.

Comment: Try doing it like this

    urlProducer = (date) => {
        const invoice = `http://localhost:3000/api/invoices${date}`
        const cust= `http://localhost:3000/api/invoices${date}&group-
                             by=customerNumber`;
        this.setState({
          urlInvoices: invoice,
          urlCustomer: cust,
          isDateSet: true
        });
      }

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
urlProducer = (date) => {
    const invoice = `http://localhost:3000/api/invoices${date}`
    const cust= `http://localhost:3000/api/invoices${date}&group-
                         by=customerNumber`;
    this.setState({
      urlInvoices: invoice,
      urlCustomer: cust,
      isDateSet: true
    });
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
```

Does this work?

Comment: No this doesn't work. It work as before. IE. the page doesn't get re-rendered immediately

Comment: I have updated my answer, try doing it like this. This is not a good approach. But this should work.

Comment: Same behavior. Not updating immediately.

Comment: as soon as I use `select` tag of HTML ie whenever `groupBySelector` function is evoked.

Comment: but it doesn't update on your ```DateSelector ``` component?

Comment: Yes. It saves the state. But page only get re-rendered whenever `groupBySelector` is called

Comment: In your dateHandler func trying doing this ```this.forceUpdate()``` after you call the prop method.

Comment: Tried this. Same issue persists.