# Combining two arrays based on properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays,

```
let student = [{ id: "weqwe", name: "john" }, { id: "wqeqweq", name: "doe" }]
let details = [
    { id: "2qweqweq", name: "larry", oName: "john" },
    { id: "231234qa", name: "jacob", oName: "john" },
    { id: "wetyrqwte", name: "jane", oName: "doe" }
]
```

I need to check through each object in details array and compare it with student array (compare with oName property in details array with name property in student array) and need to add an array of the details as on object property. Also need to remove the **oName**, I have tried in es6 but dynamically creating array and pushing gives only the last value, Please see the below expected output,

```
let output = [
    {
        id: "weqwe",
        name: "john",
        details: [
            { id: "2qweqweq", name: "larry" },
            { id: "231234qa", name: "jacob" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "wqeqweq",
        name: "doe",
        details: [
            { id: "wetyrqwte", name: "jane" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: let results = details.map(d => Object.assign({}, d, student.map(s => d.oName === s.name)))

Comment: `i need to check through each object in details array and compare it with student array` -- compare what? compare the objects? or any property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: comapare oName of each object in details array with name of each object in student array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
let student = [{ id: "weqwe", name: "john" }, { id: "wqeqweq", name: "doe" }]
let details = [
    { id: "2qweqweq", name: "larry", oName: "john" },
    { id: "231234qa", name: "jacob", oName: "john" },
    { id: "wetyrqwte", name: "jane", oName: "doe" }
];
let output = [{
        id: "weqwe",
        name: "john",
        details: [
            { id: "2qweqweq", name: "larry" },
            { id: "231234qa", name: "jacob" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "wqeqweq",
        name: "doe",
        details: [
            { id: "wetyrqwte", name: "jane" }
        ]
    }
];
let result = student.map((obj) => {
    obj.details = details.filter(o => o.oName === obj.name).map(({oName,...other}) =>other);
    return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why you delete property in map simply return others values from object except the oName. There is no need to delete oName. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: there is  'return o' after delete property@ZeeshanAfzalSatti

Comment: You can do this like : object.map(({oName, ...other})=> other)}

Answer (score 1):

```
let student = [{id:"weqwe", name:"john"}, {id:"wqeqweq", name:"doe"}]
let details = [
              {id:"2qweqweq", name:"larry", oName:"john"},
              {id:"231234qa", name:"jacob", oName:"john"},
              {id:"wetyrqwte", name:"jane", oName:"doe"}
              ]


let output= student.map(student=> {

  const detailsObj = details.filter(({oName})=>  oName === student.name)
  return {...student, details: detailsObj.map(({oName, ...other})=> other)}
})

console.log(output)
```