# Update the object value using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to update an array of objects list using javascript.

How to update the `objList` with the `newObjList` by matching the `id` and `name`.
If the `id` and `name` matches, then update the `objList` nested array object.

```
var result = updateObj(objList, newObjList);
console.log(result);

function updateObj(list, newObjList){
  var flatarr = list.map(e=>Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3);
  var filterService =  newObjList.filter(e=>e.name=="service");
  //got stuck
}

var newObjList=[{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
},{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 5000
}]


var objList=[
{
  "btob": [{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 1000
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 5000
   }]
},{
 "ctob":[{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 1000,
    "rate": 0.4
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 3000,
    "rate": 0.2
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 4000,
    "rate": 0.6
   }]
  }]
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
var result=[
{
  "btob": [{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 5000
   }]
},{
 "ctob":[{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 5000,
    "rate": 0.4
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 3000,
    "rate": 0.2
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 4000,
    "rate": 0.6
   }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following;

```
var flatList = objList.flatMap(obj => obj["btob"] || obj["ctob"]);
newObjList.forEach(newObj => flatList
       .filter(obj => obj.id == newObj.id && obj.name == newObj.name)
       .forEach(obj => Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => obj[key] = newObj[key])));
```

As you can see the code is very clean & readable, first flattening the targeted `objList` to make it more easily accessible, then just iterate `newObjList`, find the targeted objects in the flattened list, and update them. This update logic is done via `Object.keys()` because OP wants object update without any hardcoded keys in the process.

You can see it in action in below snippet;

```js
var newObjList = [{
  "id": "service",
  "name": "bank",
  "amount": 2000
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "name": "credit",
  "amount": 5000
}];

var objList = [{
  "btob": [{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 1000
  }, {
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
  }, {
    "id": "others",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 5000
  }]
}, {
  "ctob": [{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 1000,
    "rate": 0.4
  }, {
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 3000,
    "rate": 0.2
  }, {
    "id": "others",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 4000,
    "rate": 0.6
  }]
}];

var flatList = objList.flatMap(obj => obj["btob"] || obj["ctob"]);
newObjList.forEach(newObj => flatList
  .filter(obj => obj.id == newObj.id && obj.name == newObj.name)
  .forEach(obj => Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => obj[key] = newObj[key])));

console.log(objList);
```

Comment: thanks for help, but want to return the obj without hardcoding keys ( `obj.amount`)

Comment: @Senthil check again, I updated the logic so that key values are not hardcoded. But it will insert new fields from `newObj`, for example, can insert a `"rate": 0.4` to an obj in `objList` that had no such field, is that correct behaviour you want?

Answer (score 0):

The code below would generate the required object dynamically without any hardcoding on keys or values. If you want to return a totally new object then probably you can change return in the `map` function below to `{... a}` and `{... childObj}` as per ES6 to get a new copy of the inner objects.

```js
function updateObj(list, newobj){
  const result = [];
  objList.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).map(k => {
      const newRootObj = {};
      newRootObj[k[0]] = k[1].map(childObj => {
        const a = newObj.find(nObj => nObj.id === childObj.id && nObj.name === childObj.name);
        if(a) {
          childObj.amount = a.amount;
        }
        return childObj;
      });
      result.push(newRootObj);
    });
  });
  return result;
}

const newObj=[{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
},{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 5000
}];


const objList=[
{
  "btob": [{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 1000
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 2000
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "bank",
    "amount": 5000
   }]
},{
 "ctob":[{
    "id": "service",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 1000,
    "rate": 0.4
  },{
    "id": "fund",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 3000,
    "rate": 0.2
  },{
    "id": "others",
    "name": "credit",
    "amount": 4000,
    "rate": 0.6
   }]
  }];

const result = updateObj(objList, newObj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a solution that relied on no hardcoding at all - that is, no `"btob"` or `"ctob"`, you could use a `.map()` to loop through `objList`. For each item in it, loop through all of it's key/value pairs, and update matches using `.find()`. This also leaves your original object in-tact as opposed to overriding it.

Consider the sample below where I've added an additional key to demonstrate the extensibility.

```js
var newObj = [
  { "id": "service", "name": "bank", "amount": 2000 },
  { "id": "service", "name": "credit", "amount": 5000 },
  { "id": "test", "name": "test", "newKey": "Hello world!"}
]; 
var objList = [
  { "btob": [{ "id": "service", "name": "bank", "amount": 1000 },{ "id": "fund", "name": "bank", "amount": 2000 },{ "id": "others", "name": "bank", "amount": 5000 }] },
  { "ctob":[{ "id": "service", "name": "credit", "amount": 1000, "rate": 0.4 },{ "id": "fund", "name": "credit", "amount": 3000, "rate": 0.2 },{ "id": "others", "name": "credit", "amount": 4000, "rate": 0.6 }]}, 
  { "dtob": [{ "id": "test", "name": "test"}]}
];

let result = objList
  .map(root => Object.keys(root)
    .reduce((output,key) => (
      {...output, [key]: root[key]
        .flatMap(i => {
          let replacement = newObj.find(f => i.id === f.id && i.name === f.name);
          return replacement ? {...i, ...replacement} : i;
        })
      }
    ), {})
  );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through both the arrays and modify if matches your condition.

**Update**: See how the nested(one level depth in your sample) objects are iterated.

```
objList.forEach(items => {
   items.forEach(item => {
      newObj.some(entry => {

          if (item.id === entry.id && item.name === entry.name) {
             item.amount = entry amount;
             return true;      //Break the inner loop (if no duplicate entries expected in objList) 
          }

      })
   })
})
```

Observe how the original array objects are referenced directly.