# React JS comparing a value from two different array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a simple solution to compare just the "id" values and "type" in from two different arrays of objects as the following:

```
var arr_a = [
  { id: 1, name: "thumbler", type: "add" },
  { id: 2, name: "spoon", type: "add" },
  { id: 3, name: "plate", type: "add" },
];

var arr_b = [
  { id: 1, name: "thumbler", type: "remove" },
  { id: 2, name: "spoon", type: "add" },
  { id: 3, name: "plate", type: "add" },
  { id: 4, name: "fork", type: "add" },
];
```

and I wanna a result like this:

```
var arr_c = [
  { id: 1, name: "thumbler", type: "remove" },
  { id: 4, name: "fork", type: "add" },
];
```

I tried to use filter and some ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863131/compare-2-two-different-arrays-and-show-the-object-with-the-same-value-with-js)) but doesn't work:

```
var arr_c = arr_b.filter(
  (x) =>
    arr_a.filter((y) => y.id === x.id && y.action_type === x.action_type)
      .length > 0
);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to compare `id` and `type`, then how do you get id:1 and id:4 in the result because in the former `type` is different and in the latter id is not present in arr_a? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @ShikharAwasthi i want to get the result from compare arr_a and arr_b with condition: 
1. has same id but different type, in arr_a id:1 has type:add, and i want to show object in arr_b id:1 and type:remove. 
2. get the new record in arr_b which is id:4

Comment: so your result will contain an object whose id is not in arr_a or if the id is the same but the type is different. correct?

Comment: @ShikharAwasthi correct

Comment: ok, answered then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods of the array to achieve your result. See the snippet below.

```js
let arr_c = arr_b.filter(a => arr_a.some(a1 => a1.id === a.id && a.type !== a1.type) || arr_a.every(a1 => a1.id !== a.id))
```

Full working code:-

```js
var arr_a = [{id:1, name:"thumbler", type:"add"},
             {id:2, name:"spoon", type:"add"},
             {id:3, name:"plate", type:"add"}];

var arr_b = [{id:1, name:"thumbler", type:"remove"},
             {id:2, name:"spoon", type:"add"},
             {id:3, name:"plate", type:"add"},
             {id:4, name:"fork", type:"add"}];
var arr_c = arr_b.filter(a => arr_a.some(a1 => a1.id === a.id && a.type !== a1.type) || arr_a.every(a1 => a1.id !== a.id));

console.log(arr_c);
```

Comment: This is a better answer, I have deleted mine.