# how to make to array data types(object) as strictly equal (===) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, operators

In my application I have to make two array datatypes(one is any[] and other is number[]) as equal using strictly equal.

my code is:

**.component.ts**

```
 if (categoryIds ===  PhysicalPackageConst.nrtPatchCategory){
               this.materialTypes = PhysicalPackageConst.nrtPatchMaterialType;
categoryIds = [];
            
                  }
```

In the above *if* condition it is showing as false if I make it as ===(if I use == it is showing the data(true) but not for ===)

**package.constant.ts**

```
export const PhysicalPackageConst = {
nrtGumCategory : [29],
    nrtPatchCategory : [30]
```

So I want to make it as true for the above condition in strictly condition
Can anyone help me on this

Comment: "*In the above if condition it is showing as false if I make it as ===(if I use == it is showing the data(true) but not for ===)*" that means you do not have arrays on both sides. https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494)

Comment: No, both sides array(object datatypes  ) only

Comment: No, that is impossible. Objects are compared by identity in every single case, so `==` and `===` are exactly the same. If you say one returns `true` the other `false`, then you don't have objects on either side. Most likely you're comparing something like `"30" == [30]` which would be `true` because of implicit conversion. But not with strict equality because the types don't match.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strict Equality Comparison (===)** *("strict equality", "identity", "triple equals")* : Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal. If the values have the same type, are not numbers, and have the same value, they're considered equal. Otherwise to compare value.

```
var num = 0;
var str = '0';

console.log(num === str); // false
```

**Abstract Equality Comparison (==)** *("loose equality", "double equals")* : The behavior for performing loose equality using `==` is as follows. Loose equality compares two values for equality after converting both values to a common type. After conversions (one or both sides may undergo conversions), the final equality comparison is performed exactly as `===` performs it.

```
var num = 0;
var str = '0';

console.log(num === str); // true
```

[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

For your problem, it's logic to get those result, because you need to cast value of array :any[] to number and make strict compare.

```
let categoryIds: any[] = [];
let nrtPatchCategory: number = 30;
// browse categoryIds arrays (you can use any other method like for ...)
categoryIds.forEach(categoryId => {
  if (Number(categoryId) === nrtPatchCategory) {
    ...
  }
});
```

*Note:* For more detail of forEach() [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**Exemple:**

```
console.log(2 === Number('3')); // false
console.log(3 === Number('3')); // true
```

Comment: Thanks@Med Aziz CHETOUI , but In my requirement category Ids are array (i.e public categoryIds: any[] = []; ) and nrtPatchCategory is number(nrtPatchCategory : 30)For this How can I make it as strictly equal(===) can you please help me for this It would be helpful for my requirement

Comment: You're welcome, i edit my response and im based on your comment, i hope it's helpful.