# Finding Duplicates in array of object in javascipt by map method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate from an array of object in Javascript. Below is the code which doesnot work, it is creating Array of map of size 4.

```js
let arr = [{id: 32, name: 'Name1', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88},
  {id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 88}
];

console.log(arr)

let mp1 = new Map();
let uniqueElements = arr.map( obj => mp1.set(obj.id, obj))

console.log(uniqueElements);
```

Comment: There are 2 elements in `arr` with `id` 32. First with `name` as `Name1`, next `Name3`. When you eliminate duplicate `id` 32 - which one of these two `name`s needs to be retained?

Comment: Have you checked this StackOverflow answer that has the same question?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to explain why 4 is the wrong answer for counting unique IDs? Or maybe explain what you mean by "duplicates" - the code shown seems to say "duplicates are objects with the same `id`" - possibly you wanted something else.

Comment: My understand is since it is map with key value, last one should overwrite the previous one. Hence {id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88} should be present in final

Comment: _since it is map with key value, last one should overwrite the previous one_ - we are able to choose which one needs to stay and which ones will need to be discarded as duplicate. It may be possible to use `.reduce()` to achieve the desired objective.

Comment: You don't even need reduce. A simple for/loop will work. OP is really complicating things using `map` and `set` (imo).

Comment: @Andy, agreed. In several situations, `.reduce()` may be replaced with a `for` loop - as they are both constructs to iterate through the array.

Comment: Thanks all for reply. 
I first tried with reduce. code is below - 

```
let arr = [{id: 32, name: 'Name1', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88},
  {id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 88}]


let uniques = arr.reduce((mp1, obj) =>{mp1.set(obj.id, obj)}, new Map())
```

I was then getting error - 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet may be one possible implementation to achieve the desired objective:

```js
const discardDupeIdElements = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(
      (fin, itm) => ({
        ...fin,
        [itm.id]: itm
      }), {}
    )
  )
);

var origArr = [{
    id: 32,
    name: 'Name1',
    age: 88
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    name: 'Name2',
    age: 88
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    name: 'Name3',
    age: 88
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sam',
    age: 88
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    name: 'Name2',
    age: 88
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 88
  }
];

console.log(discardDupeIdElements(origArr));
```

**Note**

This will always keep the `last` element of a set of duplicates and ignore all earlier ones. Such as for `id` 32, it will keep the element with `name` = `Name3` and discard `Name2`.

**Fixing the OP's code**:

```js
const arr = [{id: 32, name: 'Name1', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88},
  {id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 88}
];

// console.log(arr);
// commented-out for easier viewing of the output

const mp1 = new Map();      // declared a map

arr.forEach(obj => mp1.set(obj.id, obj));
// used .forEach to iterate through the array
// and update the map

const uniqueElements = [...mp1.values()];
// used spread operator to extract 
// the values of the map into an array

console.log(uniqueElements);
// console.log the unique elements
```

**Note**

Where possible, used `const` rather than `let`.

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns the new array with the same length of the calling array

For accumulated value (here is `mp1`), you should use `reduce`

```
let uniqueElements = arr.reduce(
  (mp1, obj) => mp1.set(obj.id, obj),
  new Map()
)
```

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 32, name: 'Name1', age: 88 },
  { id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88 },
  { id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88 },
  { id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 88 },
  { id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 88 },
]

console.log(arr)
let uniqueElements = arr.reduce((mp1, obj) => mp1.set(obj.id, obj), new Map())
console.log(uniqueElements)
```

Comment: I first tried with reduce function only. Code is below -

```
let arr = [{id: 32, name: 'Name1', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 32, name: 'Name3', age: 88},
  {id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 88},
  {id: 33, name: 'Name2', age: 88},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 88}]


let uniques = arr.reduce((mp1, obj) =>{mp1.set(obj.id, obj)}, new Map())

```

But then I was getting error -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')