# How to check same property exists in single array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I would like to know whether array of object has same property value in javascript

for the array object `list1`,

`if name and country has same value, return true`

`if name same, any object country has value SG return true`

`if above two conditions fails, return false`

```
var list1=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "IN"}
]
const result1=checkObj(list1);

var list2=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "SG"}
]
const result2=checkObj(list2);

var list3=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "TH"}
]
const result3=checkObj(list3);
Expected Result:
//when passing list1
true
//when passing list2
true
//when passing list3
false
```

Comment: @Yogi thanks for reply, and link but need to compare in single array object itself, i got stuck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030/comparing-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @DavePile no, but need to compare in same array object itself,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var list1=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "IN"}
]
const result1=checkObj(list1);

console.log(result1);

var list2=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "SG"}
]
const result2=checkObj(list2);

console.log(result2);

var list3=[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "TH"}
]
const result3=checkObj(list3);

console.log(result3);

function checkObj(list){
  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
  {  
   for(j=0;j<list.length;j++)
    {
      if(j!=i){
        if(list[i].name==list[j].name){
          if(list[i].country==list[j].country || list[i].country =='SG'){
          return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution,it works, may i know how to do with es6 functions, like forEach or find, checking property in single object array

Comment: @codelearn there are many ways to solve a problem, I gave you one way. I am not your tutor. I gave you output and expect you to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the following snippet I put together an approach based on a single loop over all elements of an array. The occurrences of `name`/`country` combinations are collected in a local object `o` and checked at the end of the function.

```js
const data=[[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "IN"}
],[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "SG"},
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "DN"},
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "EN"}
],[
  {id:1, name: "sen", country: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "sen", country: "TH"}
]];

function dupes(arr){
  const o={}, // object o counts all occurrences
    // the sort makes sure the "SG" items come last in ar
    ar= arr.slice(0).sort((a,b)=>a.country==="SG" ? (b.country==="SG" ? 0 : 1) : -1);
  // a single loop over ar:
  ar.forEach(e=>{
   if(e.country!=="SG"){ // "normal" countries:
    let k=e.name+"|"+e.country;
    o[k]=(o[k]||0)+1
   } else {  // for country=="SG"
    for (let k in o)
     if (k.indexOf(e.name+"|")==0)
       o[k]++ // increase counts for all elements starting with <el.name>|
   }
  });
  return Object.values(o).some(n=>n>1)
   
}

data.forEach(d=>console.log(dupes(d)))
```